# R: How to create multiple sequential months

Tags: r

I need to create a data frame with three columns named `Store`, `Product` and `Month`.
How can I create sequential months that run from 1/1/2010 to 12/1/2010.
And then combine it to every combination of Store and Product.

The first column is `Store`:

```
Store <- c("Chain1", "Chain2")
```

The second column is ´Product`:

```
Product <- c("ABC", "DEF", "GHI")
```

And the third column should be sequential months.
So every combination of Store and Product should have a specific month.

My desired result should be like this one.

```
Store   Product Month
Chain1  ABC     1/1/2010
Chain1  ABC     2/1/2010
Chain1  ABC     3/1/2010
Chain1  ABC     4/1/2010
Chain1  ABC     5/1/2010
Chain1  ABC     6/1/2010
Chain1  ABC     7/1/2010
Chain1  ABC     8/1/2010
Chain1  ABC     9/1/2010
Chain1  ABC     10/1/2010
Chain1  ABC     11/1/2010
Chain1  ABC     12/1/2010
Chain1  DEF     1/1/2010
Chain1  DEF     2/1/2010
Chain1  DEF     3/1/2010
Chain1  DEF     4/1/2010
Chain1  DEF     5/1/2010
Chain1  DEF     6/1/2010
Chain1  DEF     7/1/2010
Chain1  DEF     8/1/2010
Chain1  DEF     9/1/2010
Chain1  DEF     10/1/2010
Chain1  DEF     11/1/2010
Chain1  DEF     12/1/2010
Chain1  GHI     1/1/2010
Chain1  GHI     2/1/2010
Chain1  GHI     3/1/2010
Chain1  GHI     4/1/2010
Chain1  GHI     5/1/2010
Chain1  GHI     6/1/2010
Chain1  GHI     7/1/2010
Chain1  GHI     8/1/2010
Chain1  GHI     9/1/2010
Chain1  GHI     10/1/2010
Chain1  GHI     11/1/2010
Chain1  GHI     12/1/2010
Chain2  ABC     1/1/2010
Chain2  ABC     2/1/2010
Chain2  ABC     3/1/2010
Chain2  ABC     4/1/2010
Chain2  ABC     5/1/2010
Chain2  ABC     6/1/2010
Chain2  ABC     7/1/2010
Chain2  ABC     8/1/2010
Chain2  ABC     9/1/2010
Chain2  ABC     10/1/2010
Chain2  ABC     11/1/2010
Chain2  ABC     12/1/2010
Chain2  DEF     1/1/2010
Chain2  DEF     2/1/2010
Chain2  DEF     3/1/2010
Chain2  DEF     4/1/2010
Chain2  DEF     5/1/2010
Chain2  DEF     6/1/2010
Chain2  DEF     7/1/2010
Chain2  DEF     8/1/2010
Chain2  DEF     9/1/2010
Chain2  DEF     10/1/2010
Chain2  DEF     11/1/2010
Chain2  DEF     12/1/2010
Chain2  GHI     1/1/2010
Chain2  GHI     2/1/2010
Chain2  GHI     3/1/2010
Chain2  GHI     4/1/2010
Chain2  GHI     5/1/2010
Chain2  GHI     6/1/2010
Chain2  GHI     7/1/2010
Chain2  GHI     8/1/2010
Chain2  GHI     9/1/2010
Chain2  GHI     10/1/2010
Chain2  GHI     11/1/2010
Chain2  GHI     12/1/2010
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use the `expand.grid` function:

```
Month <- format(seq.Date(from = as.Date("2010-01-01"), by = "m", length.out = 12), "%d/%m/%Y")

expand.grid(Store = Store, Product = Product, Month = Month, stringsAsFactors = F)
```

Comment: Thanks. How can we format the month to be "1/1/2010" ?

Comment: I edited my answer. Now the date is in the desired format.

Comment: similarly, you could also add `tidyr::crossing(Store, Product, Month = seq(as.Date("2018-01-01"), by = "month", length.out = 12))`